# Where can I find the access key secret for the HERE API?

Tags: java, android, here-api

I followed GitHub sample to integrate here (Lite edition) in my Android application but all I got is a blank activity.
When I checked my output I found this:

> E/analytics: [ERROR] analytics - Invalid access key

I checked my credentials I literally copy and paste the app_id and access_key_id. But I noticed that I need 2 parameters in my credentials that are: access_key_id and access_key_secret.

When I went back to my project credentials I only found application ID and access key id. No access key secret generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you log into the developer portfolio and then look at your project details, you can generate these values under the "HERE SDK FOR ANDROID OR IOS (LITE EDITION)" section. Click "Create credentials" under the blue OAuth 2.0 button.